# how to calculate WeekOfMonth in SQL

Tags: date

Trying to calculate holidays in a given year for loading DimDate table. There is an option in SQL to calculate the WeekOfYear Number but couldnt find a function to calculate the WeekNumberOfMonth.

How to find week number of a given month to calculate holidays in a year to fill DIMDate table

Comment: What's version of SQL program you are using of backend program? Put tags to be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

**Logic**
CurrentDateWeek - CurrentDateMonthBeginWeek
the difference between the week Number for a given date and the first week number for the given date provides week of a month

**Simple One Line SQL Statement**

```
Declare @CurrentDate as datetime
set @CurrentDate = '5/31/2014'

Select  (Datepart(week,@CurrentDate) - (Datepart(week,cast(month(@CurrentDate) as varchar) + '/1/' + cast(Year(@CurrentDate) as varchar))) + 1) as WeekOfMonth
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
Declare @CurrentDate as datetime
Declare @BeginWeek as int
Declare @EndWeek as Int
set @CurrentDate = '5/31/2014'

SET @EndWeek = DATEPART(week,eomonth(@CurrentDate))
SET @BeginWeek = Datepart(week,cast(month(@CurrentDate) as varchar) + '/1/' + cast(Year(@CurrentDate) as varchar))
Select  Datepart(week,@CurrentDate) - @BeginWeek + 1
Select @BeginWeek as beginweek
select @EndWeek as endweek
Select Datepart(week,@CurrentDate)
```

Using the above logic we could fill the DIMDATE table with holiday days